# Install self compiled software to /usr or /usr/local?

Tags: software-installation, directory-structure

Generally speaking, should self installation by compiling source be stored in `/usr` or `/usr/local` (specified to `--prefix`)?

When to install to `/usr` and when to `/usr/local`?

E.g.

1. I often  run `checkinstall` to create a deb file after compilation of source distribution, and
   `checkinstall` installs the software by calling `dpkg`. isn't this
   the same as installing software from OS repositories? After install,
   both can be managed by `dpkg`. What differences are between them?
2. I am running Ubuntu 14.04. I don't use emacs from its repository.

   I installed  my emacs by compling from source and `checkinstall`,
   the default location is `/usr/local`. e.g. `/usr/local/bin/emacs`and
   `/usr/local/share/emacs/24.4/`.

   I installed [ESS from its offical site](http://ess.r-project.org/downloads/ess/ess-15.03.tgz). The default install
   location is `/usr` e.g. `/usr/share/emacs/`. I don't find a way to
   specify `--prefix` for ESS. I run `make install` directly.

   So in my emacs, I can't find S mode offered by ESS.

   Shall I reinstall emacs with `./configure --prefix=/usr`?

Thanks!

Comment: also see [Why are custom programs always installed in /opt, /srv, /usr/local, etc. and not in ~/ (home) folder?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139003/why-are-custom-programs-always-installed-in-opt-srv-usr-local-etc-and-not)

Answer (score 1):

[You should place locally-installed software in `/usr/local`](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/HighQuality-Apps-HOWTO/fhs.html).

I have no idea what ESS is but I downloaded the file you mentioned and it looks like you could change its install location by editing `Makeconf` in its root directory and changing `PREFIX=$(DESTDIR)` to `PREFIX=/usr/local`.

Comment: thanks. why not --prefix=/usr?

Comment: @Tim, This is a common best practice to avoid conflicts with you OS own packages.

Comment: Do you mean why isn't the syntax `--prefix=/usr` for that specific software, or do you mean why is it not a good idea to install locally in `/usr`? The former: because that particular software doesn't have a `configure` script that takes that option. The latter: @Rabin already answered that.

Comment: Thanks. The latter.  ESS install things to `/usr/share/emacs/` by default, Do you think it is a bad location? ("conflicts with you OS own packages"?) Do you think changing to `/usr/local` is better than the default?

Comment: Yes, I think `/usr/local` is better than the default and I think that the developers should have published it with `/usr/local` as the default. Operating system packagers such as Debian maintainers then have the burden of overriding it to use `/usr` for the OS package only.

Comment: I call `checkinstall` to create a deb file after compilation, and `checkinstall` installs the software by calling `dpkg`. isn't this the same as installing software from OS repositories? After install, both can be managed by `dpkg`. What differences are between them?