# How can I get self-compiled packages to play nice with packages managers (e.g. apt-get, yum)

Tags: apt, compiling, yum, deb, autoconf

Suppose I want to:

- compile and install my own custom application
- which requires downloading, compiling and installing the source for newest version of libthrift
- which requires downloading, compiling and installing the latest version of libboost

Here, I'm installing these libraries in my system which may interact with other packages -- very many libraries depend on libthrift and libboost.

- installing these may break existing package installed with apt-get/yum

Also, if I later run apt-get or yum:

- my custom libthrift and libboost will be overwritten breaking my custom application that depends on custom versions of these libraries.

So, what's the solution here? I don't want to install into /home (I'd like the packages to be available to shared users in a code regression build cluster). I've also read that /opt is not really for this purpose (the packages installed should be [self-contained](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139003/why-are-custom-programs-always-installed-in-opt-srv-usr-local-etc-and-not), which they are not). The [references](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138547/how-to-understand-the-ubuntu-file-system-layout) I've found seem to cover this case in enough detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, the solution is "don't try to install from source into directories managed by your packaging system".

You can install your custom-compiled code into `/usr/local`, for example, and having anything that depends on it look to `/usr/local` for libraries and include files using appropriate invocations of your build system (e.g., setting `CPPFLAGS`/`CFLAGS`/`LDFLAGS` for a typical `Makefile`).

You could even install everything into an application-specific directory (e.g., `/usr/local/myapp`, or `/opt/myapp`).

This is also a great use case for something like [Docker](http://docker.com/), which makes it very easy to set up isolated development/runtime environments that are isolated from your host.